# Run github actions locally. nektos : | Could not fetch https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):

Tags: python-3.x, github-actions, ubuntu-22.04, nektos-act

Hi I am trying to run github actions locally and found application **ACT (nektos/act)**. While using ACT I am facing following issue:

```
uses: actions/setup-python@v4
   with:
      python-version: '3.9'
```

*Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)'))) - skipping*

I am **getting this error with ubuntu medium images**. However, it **runs fine with large ubuntu image (ubuntu:full-latest)**. But it ishuge. I have **set** the certificate using variable **NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS** (my .crt file)